# Get Some Value from Random Function in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, random

I have five value that I get from generating random function in PHP like this:

1
0
0
1
1

And this is the code:

```
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
$n = rand(0, 1);
echo $n;echo "<br/ >"}
```

And now, what should I do so that I only get the value from the first row and the third?
So I only get the value:
1
0

Comment: Why don't you just limit the output to two? Also, using `rand()` the first and third entry could also be 0 and 0 or 1 and 1…

Comment: if i =0 or i= 2 echo... ???

Comment: Just getting the first and third rows is no more random than just getting 2 rows to start with

Answer (score 6):

Use an array where you store the data and then access to it:

```
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    $data[] = rand(0, 1);
}

echo $data[0];  //1st "row"
echo '<br>';
echo $data[2];  //3rd "row"
```

Keep in mind that PHP arrays start with the index 0. 
To learn more about PHP arrays and its usage: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1):

Store your values in an array then output the ones you actually want

```
$n = array();
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    $n[] = rand(0, 1);    
}
echo $n[0];
echo '<br>';
echo $n[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    if($i == 0 || $i == 2){
        $n = rand(0, 1);
        echo $n;echo "<br/ >"
    }
}
```

but I have no idea what you want to achieve with that...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
    for($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
    {
       $n = rand(0, 1);

       if($i != 0 && $i != 2)
           continue;

       echo $n;
       echo "<br/ >";
    }
```

working example [here](http://ideone.com/uolgRM)

Answer (score 0):

Let's get rid of the for loop:

```
$data = array_map(function($v){return rand(0,1);}, range(0, 9)); // Requires PHP 5.3+ 
echo $data[0] . ' ' . $data[2];
```

[Online demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ld8zvZ).